# How to catch authentication errors in Silex?

Tags: php, error-handling, silex

I am developping a Rest API with Silex framework and I use  `SecurityServiceProvider`. However, if a user sends bad credentials throw HTTP, I don't know how I can catch the error to display something like this :

```
{"status_code":401, "error_message":"Bad credentials"}
```

Below is a part of my code:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'stateless' => true,
            'http' => true,
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new App\Providers\UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
    ),
));

// ...

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    // This code is never executed in case of Bad credentials

    // ...

    return new JsonResponse($contentResponse, $statusCode);
});
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I've seen I can use `$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.'.$name]` but it is never handled in my case.

```
$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.default'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
     // This code is never executed
     return new MySuccessHandler();
});
```

Is it because of `'http' => true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the structure of my code, I decided to check the error in the `after` middleware, throw an exception and catch it with `$app->error(...)`.

```
$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // If Unauthorized
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 401)
        throw new Exception('Unauthorized'); // This exception will be handled by "$app->error(...)"
});


$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'stateless' => true,
            'http' => true,
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new App\Providers\UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
    ),
));

// ...

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    // ...
    return new JsonResponse($contentResponse, $statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the generic `error` function you can listen to [the security events emitted by the security component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events), specifically to the *security.authentication.failure* one.

To do so, you just need to call the [`on`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L221) method:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationFailureEvent

//...
$app->on('security.authentication.failure', function(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event) {
  // you can do some checks if you want, but there's no need...

  return new JsonResponse($contentResponse, $statusCode);
});
```

Keep in mind that this is untested code.

Comment: The error is effectively handled`by `$app->on('security.authentication.failure', /* ... */) but returning a `JsonResponse` won't change anything. Instead I can display the `$contentResponse` variable.

Comment: You can try increasing the priority: ```$app->on('security.authentication.failure', function (AuthenticationFailureEvent $event) { /* ... */ }, 255);```

Comment: Increasing the priority doesn't change anything in my case

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
   // This code is never executed in case of Bad credentials

   if($e instanceof AuthenticationException){

       return new JsonResponse(["status_code"=>401, "error_message"=>"Bad credentials"], 401);
   }
   // ...

  return new JsonResponse($contentResponse, $statusCode);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work because with this kind of error, it's not handled with `$app->error(/* ... */)`